# VB.NET - SQL request do not accept = character

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

This request works great:

```
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE dat_recep > #10/14/2022# ORDER BY dat_recep DESC", conn)
```

It works with `>`, `<`, `<>` but not with `=`.

It does not generate any error, it just returns a empty table.

I do not want to use something like :

```
WHERE dat_recep < #10/15/2022# & dat_recep > #10/13/2022#
```

Any idea why `=` is not accepted ?

Comment: Maybe just because the exact matching on a date doesn't match any rows in your table? Often, dates in a SQL table also contain **time** portions - so matching with equal operator on a date is a bit tricky at times....

Comment: Which database are you using? `#10/14/2022#` is valid only in Access. Even then, it's a *very* bad idea to construct queries by concatenating user input. A parameterized query would be better

Comment: As for `it just returns a empty table` that's expected if `dat_recep` includes a time part. `#10/14/2022#` is actually `2022-10-14 00:00:00`. If you compare it for equality with values that contain any time except midnight, you'll get no match. To get all rows in the day, use `data_recep >= #10/14/2022# and data_recep < #10/15/2022#` although a better solution would be to pass the dates as parameters `data_recep >= ? and data_recep < ?` and calculate the parameter values in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` works as expected - it will allow only rows that match the *exact* datetime value, `2022-10-14 00:00:00`. Any rows whose `dat_recep` contains a time different than `00:00:00` will be filtered out.

One solution that takes advantage of indexing is to filter for rows with `dat_recep` greater or equal to `2022-10-14` but less than the next day.

```
Dim startInclusive As DateTime = somDate.Date
Dim endExclusive As DateTime = startInclusive.AddDays(1)

Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE dat_recep >= ? 
   AND dat_recep < ? 
ORDER BY dat_recep DESC"

Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start",startInclusive);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end",endExclusive);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was not aware of the "time 00:00:00" as it is the first time I use database... So I understand now that I have to use greater and less.